# Unable to understand Python code

Tags: python, python-3.6

can someone please explain how this below mentioned code works. why len and what's that [i] do? I am unable to understand this code. New to python.

```
# Program to iterate through a list using indexing

genre = ['pop', 'rock', 'jazz']

# iterate over the list using index
for i in range(len(genre)):
    print("I like", genre[i])
```

Comment: are you also new to programming? `len()` is a function call and `i` is an index. Maybe you should start off with the basics...

Comment: in this case, len(genre) would be 3 since there are 3 elements. You are looping through i in [0 - 3) and printing out the genre each time. ie. genre[0] is 'pop', genre[1] is 'rock' ...

Comment: Just read a tutorial. Any good tutorial will cover things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `range(x)` you are essentially creating a list where each item in the list is a number, ranging from 1, to `x`.
For example:

```
>>> list(range(10))
```

Will return:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

(The list function is necessary to be able to understand what it returns as otherwise we will get `range(0, 9)` as an output)

What a `for` loop actually does is goes through a list (1, 2, 3, etc..) and makes the variable `i` or what ever you call it to the current object in the list. This means that by doing

```
list = ['a', 'b' , 'c'] 

for item in list:
  print(item)
```

Will return:

```
a
b
c
```

Same as like you did.

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop is used to increment through an array. The in your example you are looping through the `genre` array.

## What the len and range is doing:

In the `range` function you input the amount of loops you want to perform. In your case you want to loop for as many entries you have in your `genre` array. The `len` function will return the size of your array making `len(genre)` return `3`, which is the amount of times you want to loop.

## What the i is doing:

The value `i` is used as a reference for each instance of the loop. For example, in the first loop `i` will equal `0` and the second time it will equal `1`. You can then use `i` as a reference to each entry in the array. For example: `genre[i]`

Comment: here this code i wrote it works the same. genre = ['pop', 'rock', 'jazz']

    # iterate over the list using index
    for i in genre:
        print("I like", i)

so what could be the difference? when they work same?

Comment: There is none really